# What is the correct way to say ? Let me put my point or let me put up my point

Tags: grammar, american-english, phrasal-verbs, speech

I would like to know what seems more accurate.

1. Let me put my point.
2. Let me put up my point.

I know that "Put up" is a phrasal verb which definitely have scenarios to be used more appropriately but I am not sure about this case.

Comment: _Put up_ has no uses that fit in this context, as far as I know.

Comment: "Let me make my point" is a lot more idiomatic, and "Let me put it this way" far more so. [[Google 5-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Let+me+put+my+point%2CLet+me+make+my+point%2CLet+me+put+it+this&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CLet%20me%20put%20my%20point%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CLet%20me%20make%20my%20point%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CLet%20me%20put%20it%20this%3B%2Cc0)]

Comment: Neither one is particularly idiomatic in AE.

Comment: @ColinFine - Unless he's planning to "can" his point.

Comment: Maybe you’re playing a game with a scoreboard and you want to put up the point you just scored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the two is correct. If the point is intended as a suggestion you can still use "put my point" (not "put up my point"), but you have to add the preposition "to" and the indirect object "you". This new verbal form is the phrasal verb "[**to put sth to sb**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/put-to#putto2_e)".

- Let me put my point to you.